# A dilemma with reading files in C

Tags: c

Its my first question, so I hope you guys can help. In class, I was tasked with writing a C code that reads a group of strings from 1 file, and print them in another file, along with the ASCII codes of each character in the string, and the sum of the ASCII code values. The code below compiled, but did not execute. Is the code right, but I did something wrong, or is the code simply wrong. Thanks a bunch.

Note: the first file reads from a text file named list, and the code prints into a text document named list2.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *file1, *file2;

    file1 = fopen("list.txt", "r");

    if (file1==NULL)
    {
        puts(" File not exisiting\n");
    }

    file2 = fopen("list2.txt", "w");

    if (file2==NULL)
    {
        puts(" File could not open \n");
    }

    char a[5];
    fscanf(file1, "%s", a);
    int b,c;

    while (a[5]!=EOF)
    {
        for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
        fprintf(file2, "%c", a[i]);
        b=a[i];
        fprintf(file2, "%d", b);

        c+=b;
        }
    }

    fprintf(file2, "%d", c);
    return 0;



}
```

Comment: there must be something wrong because theres no fclose anywhere :)

Comment: What do you mean by "did not execute"? Was there an error message? Did the program run but never finished? Please edit your question and include additional information. Thanks.

Comment: 'did not execute': please give details about what the actual error is.

Comment: Imagine a unicode txt file....

Answer (score 2):

**Point 1.** With a definition like

```
char a[5];
```

using

```
while (a[5]!=EOF)
```

invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).
You're facing off-by-one error. Remember, array index in c starts from 0. The valid access it at most upto `a[4]`.

---

**Point 2.**  `fscanf(file1, "%s", a);` is unsafe. It can cause buffer overflow. Atleast, you need to write

```
 if ( fscanf(file1, "%4s", a) != 1)
 {
         //scanning not successful, take necessary measures
 }
 //otherwise, continue nomal execution.
```

---

**Point 3.** The logic for `while` loop is not correct. You don't have a `break` condition there.

---

**Point 4.** `c+=b;`, here `c` is used uninitalized. *read-before-write* scenario. Again, [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Remember, `auto` local variables doesnot get initialized to `0` or some value automatically. You've to initialize explicitly.

---

**Point 5.** Do not continue normal execution if `if (file1==NULL)` condition satisfies. Only printing a message is not sufficient. You should discontinue the program and avoid using `file1`, `file1` etc.

---

<sup>Credits for point 5: [user4402433](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4402433/user4402433)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Include `return` in the file check as

```
if (file1==NULL)
{
    puts(" File not exisiting\n");
    return 0;
}
```

as there is no use of proceeding with the code if any one of the file is opened.
  Also initialize the value of `c=0;` before while so that any garbage value can be avoided.

The array `a[]` has to be indexed to update the file content. So place the

```
fscanf(file1, "%s", a[i]);
```

inside the `for()` loop . This is to avoid buffer overflow which occurs in rare cases.

Comment: Hi there !! Are you sure about your latest edit (addition)? If so, please explain a bit. First part of your answer is really helpful, I agree.

Comment: Thank you Sourav , I have made the change.

Comment: Thanks a million, man. It works perfectly. Just one last question: When should I add break in the while loop?